# Can I create a new conference room (Asterisk ConfBridge) through AMI?

Tags: asterisk

Can I create a new conference room (Asterisk ConfBridge) through Asterisk Manager Interface (AMI)? Help me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic conference(without room exist) feature and create  calls using Originate command to application Confbridge.

Comment: I can't create conference in such a way.

"Action: Originate"
"ActionID: CreateConference"
 "Channel: SIP/107"
"Timeout: 30000" 
 "CallerID: Asterisk <6000>"
 "Aplication: ConfBridge" 
 "Async: true" 
 "Data: 1234"

Where I have a mistake?

Comment: have be "Application",no? Also can be issues with callerid, try first without action,timeout,async and callerid.

Comment: action - same obligatory parameter. I can't move away it. the Application ConfBridge is. As the static conference room works when i call on number of conference room

Comment: Thank you very much! I am a fool. Not so I typed

Comment: @arheops Do you know what is the meaning of the Channel argument in this case? Will the conference be empty?

Comment: Channel in originate mean where to call first. Conference will be empty or not empty. Depend of how many times you do that/how many users

Answer (score 1):

This response is for anyone who has struggled as me to do this, even if the first response and the comments to it may be enough.

So, you can originate a conference call, with the action Originate and the application ConfBridge (as far as i know, it comes with Asterisk, not independent).

You can see all the available fields here http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Originate

I will throw an example without every field, but the ones I know and needed on my app.

This is what you throw at the Asterisk Manager Interface, if you want to call someone into a conference, then add someone else (without the comments ofc.)

```
Action: Originate // The action type
ActionID: CreateConf-1 // This id will be linked to further events about the action
Channel: SIP/1001 // The sipId of the peer u wanna call
Timeout: 30000 // If he doesnt respons in 30000ms, drop it
CallerID: Asterisk // The id of the caller (will be seen on target phone)
Application: ConfBridge // The application
Async: true // (NOT SURE, MAYBE BULLSHIT) If false, i think you can no longer originate while he hasn't answered
Data: 1234 // Very important, this is like the conference id, will detail above

Action: Originate
ActionID: CreateConf
Channel: SIP/1000
Timeout: 30000
CallerID: Asterisk
Application: ConfBridge
Async: true
Data: 1234
```

So with this, one block at time, two guys will be called into a conference.
As you saw the `Data` field represents the identifier of the call, so if you wanna give your conference an id, use it. This way you could create and manage different conferences.

Since i work with NAMI (the nodejs library for Asterisk Manager Interface) (https://github.com/marcelog/Nami), let me also drop you how to do thanks to the lib.

```
var namiLib = require('nami');
var namiInstance = new (namiLib.Nami)(config); // See more about config (and everything else about nami) in their docs
namiInstance.open();

var action = new namiLib.Actions.Originate();
action.channel = 'SIP/1000';
action.data = '12345'; // my conferenceId
action.timeout = 30000;
action.callerID = 'Metisse\'s king';
action.application = 'ConfBridge';
action.async = true;

namiInstance.send(action, function (response) {
     // deal with the response
});
```

Obviously, if you need to use NAMI to have control other Asterisk, you have to do something more generic to handle sending your actions and validating them, also watching for errors.

Answer (score -1):

No. You can use an AMI redirect to transfer your call to a piece of dialplan code that would read a channel variable, database look up or some other mechanism to set up a new conference, however.

For a full list of AMI actions for ConfBridge, please see:  https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ConfBridge+10#ConfBridge10-ConfBridgeAsteriskManagerInterface(AMI)Actions